# PHP SQL Запрос Count (*)

Tags: php, html, sql

Есть код

```
$num_rows=0;
if ($result=mysqli_query($link,'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news'))
{
    $num_rows=???$result;
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Что нужно написать на месте трех вопросиков, чтобы в переменную $num_rows записалось целое число, которое будет собственно отображать результат SQL запроса (Число записей в таблице)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а переписать немного код не подходит?

```
$num_rows = 0;
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM news");
if ($result) {
    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $num_rows = $data['total'];
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает. Просто у меня изначально было: select *from news. а потом я делал $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result).

Comment: Сказали, что это плохо делай через Count (*)

Comment: через count сильно лучше - сервер знает, что нужно только кол-во строк. И некоторые базы данных такой запрос отрабатывают моментально (вроде мускуль умеет).

Comment: "мускуль" ничего не умеет ) умеют подсистемы хранения, и то не все. Тот же InnoDB ведет реальный подсчет записей (правда, индекс считает, а не записи), а MyISAM сразу количество вернет, т.к. хранит статистику

Answer (score 1):

```
$num_rows=$pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news')->fetchColumn();
```

К вопросу о разнице между mysqli и PDO.